# Unable to set value of select option to first element in ngFor loop with Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a select input with an ngFor loop in it to create the options based on colors array.

The behavior i need is to automatically select the first option and to so that angular reactive forms can get its value when the input is created/changed.

So far my form, it looks like this :

```
<form [formGroup]="stepOneForm">
  <label for="modelSelect">Model:</label>
  <select id="modelSelect" formControlName="model">
    <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let model of models" [value]="model.code">
      {{ model.description }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <!-- The input i am interested in -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="stepOneForm.get('model')?.value as code">
    <label for="colorSelect">Color:</label>
    <select id="colorSelect" formControlName="color" (change)="onColorSelected()" [value]="colors[0].code">
      <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color.code">
        {{ color.description }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <img [src]="imagePath" alt="car">
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

And my TS part looks like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getModels().subscribe(models => {
      this.models = models;
    });

    this.stepOneForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.carService.updateStepOneValidity(this.stepOneForm.valid);
      const model = this.stepOneForm.get('model')?.value
      this.colors = this.models.find(modelObj => modelObj.code === model)?.colors ?? [];
      
      console.log(this.stepOneForm.get('color')?.value) // This returns '' (empty string)
      
      if (model) {
        this.carService.updateShoppingCart(this.stepOneForm.value)
      }
    })
  }
```

When the ng-container content gets displayed, the subscription gets triggered and on the color input I see a color selected by default, but on this line I get an empty string while i should get the value of this option :

> console.log(this.stepOneForm.get('color')?.value)

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that you are replacing the colors array in response to any form change. You should really narrow what you are responding to when you replace the array. It would be helpful if you created a stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only updating the view, but to update `color` form control value programmatically when updating `model` form control, it has to be done with form methods, from the component, with `.setValue/.patchValue`.

So, you could add a listener to the first select, and then update `color` form control.

```
<select id="modelSelect" formControlName="model" (change)="onModelSelected()">
```

```
  onModelSelected() {
    this.stepOneForm.get('color').setValue(this.colors[0]?.code || '');
  }
```

You could do it from the existing `valueChanges` by adding `{emitEvent: false}`, to prevent infinite loop, but then the colors select wouldn't work, so you need to do it from the first select, i.e. you need extra listener.